# Canvas animation speeds up after window resized

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this canvas animation of some floating clouds and dropping box:

```
var canvas, canvas_overlay, context, ctx_overlay, clouds, 
docWidth, docHeight, img_box, img_cloud1, img_cloud2, img_cloud3, img_ground;

img_box = new Image();
img_cloud1 = new Image();
img_cloud2 = new Image();
img_cloud3 = new Image();
img_ground = new Image();
img_box.src = 'images/gift_box_small.png';
img_cloud1.src = 'images/cloud1.png';
img_cloud2.src = 'images/cloud2.png';
img_cloud3.src = 'images/cloud3.png';
img_ground.src = 'images/ground_pattern_small.jpg';

var mustBeReadyCount = 6; // must load image and window

img_box.onload = launchWhenReady;
img_cloud1.onload = launchWhenReady;
img_cloud2.onload = launchWhenReady;
img_cloud3.onload = launchWhenReady;
img_ground.onload = launchWhenReady;
window.onload = launchWhenReady;

function launchWhenReady() {
    mustBeReadyCount--;
    if (mustBeReadyCount) return;
    init();
};

function init(){
    docWidth = window.innerWidth;
    docHeight =  window.innerHeight;
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas_overlay = document.getElementById('canvas_overlay');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx_overlay = canvas_overlay.getContext('2d');
    resizeCanvas(docWidth, docHeight);
    drawGround();

    var cloud1 = new Cloud(0, 10, docWidth, docHeight, img_cloud1, 3, 24);
    var cloud2 = new Cloud(Math.floor(docWidth/4*3), 48, docWidth, docHeight, img_cloud2, 5, 24);
    var cloud3 = new Cloud(Math.floor(docWidth/2), 90, docWidth, docHeight, img_cloud3, 1, 24);
    clouds = [cloud1, cloud2, cloud3];
    boxAnimationData.animationStep = 'falling';
    boxAnimationData.bounceHeight = (docHeight / 2 - img_box.height)-25;
    setInterval(createAnimations, 24);
}

var animationStep = '';
var boxAnimationData = {
    animationStep: '',
    y: 0-img_box.naturalHeight,
    maxY: 0,
    bounceCount: 10,
    direction: -1,
    bounceHeight: 0
};

window.onresize = function(){
    init();
}

function resizeCanvas(width, height){        
    canvas.width = canvas_overlay.width = docWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas_overlay.height = docHeight;
}

function drawGround(){
    var pattern=context.createPattern(img_ground,"repeat");
    context.rect(0,docHeight-50,docWidth,50);
    context.fillStyle=pattern;
    context.fill();
}

function drawClouds(clouds, width, height){
    var img;
    var arrLength = clouds.length;

    context.clearRect(0,0,width,height-50);

    for(var i=0; i<arrLength; i++){

        var cloud = clouds[i];
        img = cloud.getFilename();
        imageWidth = img.naturalWidth;
        imageHeight = img.naturalHeight;
        context.drawImage(img, cloud.getX()-imageWidth, cloud.getY());
        clouds[i].moveCloud(imageWidth);
    }       
}

function createAnimations() {
    drawClouds(clouds, docWidth, docHeight);
    if (boxAnimationData.animationStep == 'falling') dropBox();
    else if (boxAnimationData.animationStep == 'bouncing') bounceBox();
}

function dropBox() {
    ctx_overlay.clearRect(0, 0, docWidth, docHeight);
    boxAnimationData.y += 3;
    if (boxAnimationData.y + img_box.height + 25 > docHeight) {
        boxAnimationData.animationStep = 'bouncing';
    }

    ctx_overlay.drawImage(img_box, (docWidth / 2) - (img_box.width / 2), boxAnimationData.y);
}


function bounceBox() {
    ctx_overlay.clearRect(0, 0, docWidth, docHeight);
    boxAnimationData.y += boxAnimationData.direction * 3;
    if (boxAnimationData.y + img_box.height + 25 > docHeight) {
        // reached floor? swap direction
        boxAnimationData.direction *= -1;
        //  and reduce jump height
        boxAnimationData.bounceHeight *= 10 / 9;
        boxAnimationData.bounceCount--;
        if (!boxAnimationData.bounceCount) boxAnimationData.animationStep = '';

    } else if (boxAnimationData.y < boxAnimationData.bounceHeight) {
        boxAnimationData.direction *= -1;
    }
    ctx_overlay.drawImage(img_box, (docWidth / 2) - (img_box.width / 2), boxAnimationData.y);
}

function Cloud (x, y, width, height, filename, velocity, rate) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.filename = filename;
    this.velocity = velocity;
    this.rate = rate;
}

Cloud.prototype = {
    constructor:Cloud,
    moveCloud:function(imageWidth){
        if(this.x >= this.width+imageWidth){
            this.x=0-imageWidth/2;
        } else {
            this.x += this.velocity;
        }
    },
    getFilename:function(){
        return this.filename;
    },
    getX:function(){
        return this.x;
    },
    getY:function(){
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

You can watch it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/f2pd36yq/

When the window is being resized (browser window, or a mobile device changes orientation), I want either to restart the animation, or, preferably, to continue from the same point, but the clouds and the box should get new document width and height. Also, if the box is already stopped at the bottom, it should not be animated again. But what I have now is some weird animation speed up when the window is being resized.

Why is it happening and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're firing the `init` function every time on resize, so the `setInterval(createAnimations, 24);` at the bottom of the function is being fired again on every resize event.

To fix this, simply move the `setInterval` outside of the `init` function or only call `init` when it's *actually initialized* and update the other variables using a separate function on resize

Comment: Yup, that was it, thank you very much! Had to shift a few more things around to stop animating the box if it's already stopped at the bottom. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and but had a different implementation,
I just solved it by calling requestAnimationFrame(render) on window resize instead of the function render itself

```
function render {
    ...
}

requestAnimationFrame(render)

window.addEventListener('resize', requestAnimationFrame(render))
```

It will add render function to animationFrame stack and would not speed up the scene itself